# Как запросить информацию с api.owencloud.ru?

Tags: php, api

Я немного знаю php, и нужно с помощью API выводить информацию, получаемую в JSON.

В документации что-то вроде этого

```
POST /v1/auth/open HTTP/1.1
Host: api.owencloud.ru
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 68
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
{
    "login":"admin@owen.cloud",
    "password":"password123"
}
```

Но я не понимаю как этим пользоваться.
Сама документация тут https://api.owencloud.ru/

Пробовал вот так, но выходит пустая страница. И я не понимаю что делает этот алгоритм.

```
$dataString = '{
    "login":"admin@owen.cloud",
    "password":"password123"
}';

$url = 'https://api.owencloud.ru/v1/auth/open';

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dataString);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'POST /v1/auth/open HTTP/1.1',
    'Host: api.owencloud.ru',
    'Accept: */*',
    'Content-Length: 68',
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
]);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
curl_close($ch);
```

Мне бы хотя бы пример какой-то, а дальше я сам

Comment: Примеров на этом сайте - вагон и маленькая тележка. Вы попробовали хоть один?

Comment: Пробовал, просто пустую страницу получаю в лучшем случае.

Comment: Но хотя бы заголовок нормальный можно было дать вопросу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

curl(нужно подставить валидный логин и пароль):

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d '{"login":"admin@owen.cloud", "password":"password123"}' https://api.owencloud.ru/v1/auth/open
```

php:

```
<?php
// URL запроса
$url = 'https://api.owencloud.ru/v1/auth/open';

// Данные для передачи
$data = array(
    'login' => '"admin@owen.cloud',
    'password' => 'password123'
);

// Преобразование данных в формат x-www-form-urlencoded
$data = http_build_query($data);

// Инициализация CURL-сессии
$ch = curl_init();

// Установка параметров запроса
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Выполнение запроса и получение ответа
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// Закрытие CURL-сессии
curl_close($ch);

// Вывод ответа
echo $response;
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Ответ от сервера получил, правда с ошибками, но уже что-то. 
На php было пусто потому что я запускал с локального сервера.